Problem accessing KeyVault during Azure Function deployment with GithubAction
I'm doing a deployment for an Azure Function using Github Action. My function has this env var:

But when I run the Action the deployment fails with this error:

If i check the log from Application Insight I find this problem that make me think that there are some problems accessing the keyvault (although the function has access):


In fact if I change the value of AzureWebJobStorage using plain connection string (eg "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName= ...") the deployment works just fine. 
The thing that I found most tricky is that if, after the successful deployment, I revert the env var AzureWebJobStorage to point again to the KeyVault all the next deployments work!!!
Someone can explain to me what is happening here? Thanks a lot.

Add Environment Variables in the GitHub Repo => Settings => Secret and Variables and check once.It should work

Also make sure the value is in correct format @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)

Warning clearly says , value is invalid..check the format once again.For more clarity try it in new function app as your old app is working now.

I've checked the value of the var inside the Kudu console of the azure func and its correct

Can you please share the complete val by masking the string

@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://{my-kv}/secrets/storageConnectionString); DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={my-strAcc};AccountKey=FTTW....Wwg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Once check the end of the val, i think you are missing the end /)

Add the end of what? At then end of the connection string (core.windows.net/) or at the end of the @Microsoft.KeyVault string (/secrets/storageConnectionString/) ?

End of @Microsoft.KeyVault string

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
